# Data tabel is adding a character automatically which I don't want

Tags: java, jsp, datatables, jstl, data-representation

So, I have been pulling up string values from my database and displaying them on JSP using JSTL and I am using jQuery datatable to do so. Some of the strings are appearing with an extra ' character at the beginning. Is there any way to fix it? I have checked the data in the database and in controllers they are coming up alright. I have deleted datatable code and Everything is fine, but I need to use it. Please help.

Comment: Look at the data at each step from when it leaves the db til it is rendered in the table.... at some point it must change in order for that char to appear? Or maybe there's a bug in the datatable? Pretty hard to tell from what you've supplied

Comment: I have checked it at every single step, it doesn't change until on JSP page. I have tried removing data table code and it worked, no added character. But I need data table for pagination and sort/search. This is the data table code I am using,  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").DataTable();
});

Comment: I got way around the issue by stripping the first character of the string before I use it for further retrieval of data. Not an efficient way but had to do it.